# Return the city name whose population is the highest

Tags: java, arraylist

The return type is "ProvinceTerritory".
which is the class name
getPopulation() and getName() are the accessors inside ProvinceTerritory class.
Also provinces is the name of the ArrayList that contains all cities with their population.I am trying to find the max population using a forach loop and then ask the program to return the name of that cell .

```
public ProvinceTerritory getHighestPopulation(){
int max = provinces.get(0).getPopulation();
for(ProvinceTerritory pt3 : provinces){
    if(pt3.getPopulation() > max){
        max = pt3.getPopulation();
    }

}
return ??;
}
```

Comment: does your `ProvinceTerritory` class have a `name` property or something similar?

Comment: Your problem is a little confusing. You want to return the name, but your return type is `ProvinceTerritory`. Either way, just declare a variable before your foreach loop, and set it inside the if statement, much like you are now with `max`, then return that value.

Comment: Create an instance of ProvinceTerritory and update when your condition matches and return the same.

Comment: @developi it would be helpful if you can post the `ProvinceTerritory`class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't remember the max population, remember the `ProvinceTerritory` with the max population:

```
public ProvinceTerritory getHighestPopulation() {
    ProvinceTerritory max = null;
    for (ProvinceTerritory pt3 : provinces)
        if (max == null || pt3.getPopulation() > max.getPopulation())
            max = pt3;
    return max;
}
```

Or the Java 8 Stream version:

```
public ProvinceTerritory getHighestPopulation() {
    return provinces.stream()
                    .max(Comparator.comparingInt(ProvinceTerritory::getPopulation))
                    .orElse(null);
}
```

Comment: suppose the method should return a String as the question ask about the `name of that cell`

Comment: You could probably call `Optional.get()`, considering that OP is calling `provinces.get(0)`.

Comment: @shmosel True, but I wanted the two versions here to behave the *same*, so I made the second behave like the first. The fact that question code throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException` on empty list is likely unintended, i.e. OP didn't consider the case. Lack of *defined* behavior allows me to behave differently. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of the ProvinceTerritory that has the highest population so you can return it.

```
public ProvinceTerritory getHighestPopulation(){
    int max = provinces.get(0).getPopulation();
    ProvinceTerritory result = provinces.get(0);
    for(ProvinceTerritory pt3 : provinces){
        if(pt3.getPopulation() > max){
            max = pt3.getPopulation();
            result = pt3;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You need to initialize `result`.

Comment: Compilation error: *The local variable result may not have been initialized*